# Replace immutable.js list with a new list

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs, flux, immutable.js

I'm learning Immutable.js, and created an immutable list with the following elements:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Person 1",
    "address":"Street 1",
    "city":"Barcelona"
  },
  {
    "name":"Person 2",
    "address":"Street 2",
    "city":"Oslo"
  },
  {
    "name":"Person 3",
    "address":"Street 3",
    "city":"Tucson"
  }
]
```

Those elements are callable based on an action (I'm using React with the Flux pattern), that updates the state accordingly. What I need currently, is to update the above list (which is saved on state) with a new list, so that when my action is called, I get a new List. To be more clear:

```
// output the above list
const details = this.state.customers.get('details')

// action to store my list. 
// Should override the last one each time my list changes
clientAction.setNewCustomersData({details: details})
```

So when I call my state inside render `this.state.customers.get('details')`, it outputs my new list. I'm almost sure that it's a little something I'm missing but I'm getting lost about how immutable treat changes this way (since it's 'imuutable' after all).

**EDIT:**

`clientAction.setNewCustomersData({details: details})`

under the hood is declared as:

`globalState.mergeIn(['company', 'customers'], myAction.setNewCustomersData)`

Comment: Can you show your `setNewCustomersData` code?

Comment: Sure, updated for you :)